# cannot open sfml-system.lib in Visual code 2022 for C++ setup

Tags: c++, visual-studio, game-development

Am setting up project for game development and am facing this issue both in debug and release
[screen shot of Visual Studio ] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyMpl.png)

AM expecting to run this code or program. I did everything correct. I am using 64 bit, both SFMLand visual code

Comment: Can not open a lib in msvc usually means 1 or more of the following: 1) the file name or path you entered in your IDE is wrong, 2) You are mixing 32 and 64 bit or 3) The library file is corrupt.

Comment: Is there any update? What about the full path of lib in properties: linker -> Input? Such as XXX/XX/sfml-system-d.lib. And  pay attention to whether your project is  `DEBUG` mode, the attribute page is `Active`